# Word VBscript - Remove extra lines in and after table

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a Word vbscript that sets a company signature.  I'm trying to figure out how to add lines before the table and remove the extra lines that are showing up after the table.

Here's the code:

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

strName = objUser.FullName
strFirst = objUser.FirstName
strLast = objUser.LastName
strInitials = objUser.Initials
strOffice = objUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
strPOBox = objUser.postOfficeBox
strTitle = objUser.Description
strCred = objUser.info
strStreet = objUser.StreetAddress
strLocation = objUser.l
strPostCode = objUser.PostalCode
strPhone = objUser.TelephoneNumber
strMobile = objUser.Mobile
strFax = objUser.FacsimileTelephoneNumber
strEmail = objUser.mail
strCompany = objUser.Company

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Const END_OF_STORY = 6

Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 1
Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 2

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature

Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

Dim rngCell
Set rngCell = objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range
objTable.Columns(1).Width = 50
objTable.Columns(2).Width = 360
rngCell.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
rngCell.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
rngCell.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 12
rngCell.Text = strFirst & " " & strInitials & " " & strLast & " | " & _
               strOffice & " | " & strCompany & vbCr
rngCell.Font.Bold = True
rngCell.Font.Name = "Calibri"
rngCell.Font.Size = 10
rngCell.Collapse 0  'wdCollapseEnd
rngCell.MoveEnd 1, -1  'wdCharacter, 1
rngCell.Text = strStreet & " | " & strPOBox & " | " & strLocation & vbCr
rngCell.Font.Bold = False
rngCell.Font.Name = "Calibri"
rngCell.Font.Size = 10
rngCell.Collapse 0  'wdCollapseEnd
rngCell.MoveEnd 1, -1  'wdCharacter, 1
rngCell.Text = vbCr & "Phone: " & strPhone & " | " & "Fax: " & strFax & " | " & "Email: " & vbCr
rngCell.Font.Bold = False
rngCell.Font.Name = "Calibri"
rngCell.Font.Size = 10
rngCell.Collapse 0  'wdCollapseEnd
rngCell.MoveEnd 1, -1  'wdCharacter, 1
Set objLink = objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range
objLink.Hyperlinks.Add rngCell, "mailto:" & strEmail,,,strEmail
objLink.Font.Size = 10
objLink.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.EndKey END_OF_STORY
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()

objSignatureEntries.Add "Reply Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Reply Signature"

objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

(I removed the logo/image in the first column for security reasons), but for some reason, there are extra lines below the text & logo (when it's there) within the table, and there are extra lines below the table.  I need  those to disappear if possible?  Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing any picture, but your problem description indicates there should be one that illustrates the problem?

Comment: The part about "extra lines below the text and logo... and below the table" isn't clear. There will always be one empty paragraph below a table - Word requires it for structural reasons and you can't get rid of it. But I don't see code that's working outside the table, so we need more information on that point. Might be good to make that a separate question as it has nothing to do with the other question, which I've answered.

Comment: Hello again, Cindy :).  Sorry for the confusion.  What I meant is - If you look at the border on the table, it seems to be more than a line below the text.  Is it possible to have it set to directly underneath the text?  I'm trying to get rid of as much space as possible below the text & table.

Comment: It really depends so much on the content of the entire table ROW, and that's impossible for us to know at this remove. Are you familiar with Word's non-printing characters view - the "backwards P" button in Home/Paragraph? With that turned on you can see what kind of CHARACTERS may be in the cell(s). There's also CELL PADDING (margins) - you can check that in Table Properties/Table (and Cell)/Options. You want to make sure this - rngCell.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
- is set for ALL the cells, not just the one.

Comment: I'm just trying to have the bottom of the table hug the bottom of the text in the row.  Currently, it seems to be an extra line below the text.  I copied the signature with the table into Word and I was able to get the line to be flush with the bottom by changing the Row height is: Exactly - 0.5".  However, I've tried to accomplish this with vbscript using various variations of RowHeight, SetHeight, etc and I can't seem to get it to stick.  Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding lines before the table, best to add the lines (paragraphs, I assume) before you insert the table. So something like:

```
objRange.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(13)
objRange.Collapse 0 'end
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
```

Comment: Nevermind.  Figured out what I did wrong.  I didn't have the logo appearing in the first Column, so it wasn't shifting down with the table.